# wordpress ordering posts by value held in an acf field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am wanting to order some posts by "price" this is a value that is held in a number field the acf plugin.

I reorder the posts based on some params in the URL, the params then build a query string which I appends to the existing query string that build the loop in my archive template, my query in my archive page would look like this,

`post_type=used-cars&meta_key=price&order_by=meta_value&order=desc`

now regardless of the weather order is desc or asc the order does not change, so I am assuming is wrong withe query can anyone shed any light in to this for me pleae? How do I use an acf field to order my posts?

Comment: Did you try with this? Your answer is here. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the underscore from the orderby param, like so:

```
post_type=used-cars&meta_key=price&orderby=meta_value&order=desc
```